# About Numerical Precision Related with Zeros

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I encounted the following precision issue. I define c = a + b, but the result for 'c - a - b' does not equal zero. I am not sure how to resolve this.

'''

```
In[1]:= 
a = N[Exp[3]];
b = N[Exp[4]];
c = a + b;
c - a - b

Out[4]= 7.10543*10^-15
```

'''

Comment: What happens when you do `Chop[%]` on the final output? does it become zero?  see help on `Chop` or you can use infinite precision. `a = N[Exp[3], Infinity];
b = N[Exp[4], Infinity];` and you will get exact zero without doing `Chop`

Comment: But note that `N[Exp[3], Infinity]` just keeps it as `Exp[3]` and will not make it real number.  Once you convert things to approximate numbers, you'll get approximate numbers as result of computation.

Comment: notice also that `N[...]` use machine precision (unless you give second argument to `N`). on same PC, I typed the same thing on Matlab, and got same output: `a=exp(3);
b=exp(4);
c=a+b;
c-a-b` gives `7.1054e-15`  This is the nature of using real numbers.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPLYn.png)

Comment: You can avoid some of the problems by using `c - (a + b)` instead of `c - a - b`.  Now you will get `0.` as output. This is because the order makes difference in terms of real numbers computations (large number - small number, vs. difference of two numbers close to each others).  see `What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic`

Comment: Everything is indeed correct.  You can see the same phenomenon even on a scientific calculator. As @Nasser said, this is the nature of floating point computations.

Comment: Thank you, Nasser and Yarchik! Your comments are very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phenomenon occurs for simple cases too:

```
0.3 + 1.1 - 1.4
```

> ```
> 2.22045*10^-16`
> ```

These numbers do not have finite length in binary and so they're truncated when expressed as an inexact number. We can see this with [`RealDigits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html):

```
RealDigits[1.1, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
>   1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
>   0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 1}
> ```

The identity $1.1_{10} = 1.0001100110011_2...$ gets truncated to $53$ digits to the right of the decimal (on a $64$ bit machine). The same happens for $0.3$ and $1.4$ — and in fact only [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) can be represented exactly in floating point arithmetic.

We can see the error by expressing the truncated reals as rational numbers:

```
SetPrecision[0.3 + 1.1, ∞] - SetPrecision[1.4, ∞]
```

> ```
> 1/4503599627370496
> ```

```
N[%]
```

> ```
> 2.22045*10^-16
> ```